# "Unsupported marker type" in httpd error log

Tags: linux, httpd, apache-2.2

I found some error in httpd error log like seen below:

```
Unsupported marker type 0x4b 
Unsupported marker type 0x50
Unsupported marker type 0x50
Unsupported marker type 0x50
Unsupported marker type 0x50
```

Can somebody help me fix these errors?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be caused by ImageMagick, from [googling](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Unsupported+marker+type+0x50) "Unsupported marker type", you get a whole raft of bugs that are ImageMagick related.

I'm going to make a wild guess, and say that one of the scripts that your Apache is serving makes calls to ImageMagick, either in PHP, Perl or Python (probably), and that it's trying to handle a corrupt JPEG or other image file.

You should probably check what images it's handling at the time of the error, and then you might have a clearer idea about what's going on.

Comment: Great answer Tom, pity the original poster hasn't discovered google yet, or perhaps they're just astonishingly lazy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respons. TO handle image, i didn't use ImageMagick, i used GD. Is it related ?

Comment: Hi Chopper3, I have searched in google, and i found the same answer. But, i'm not sure if it was the related to GD, since i used it for handling image.

Comment: @patrixsk I suspect that it's probably the same root cause though.